# Jquery Dialog Pop up disappears

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup

I am trying to create a pop up of an image element that is rendered by sharepoint. I am very noob at jquery. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code: (.imageCss is the image class that is rendered by sharepoint).

```js
$(".imagecss").on("click", function()
{
var dialogBox = $(document.createElement('div'));
$(dialogBox).dialog();
$(dialogBox).html(this);
});
```

I am able to display the images on a dialog. But what happens is, when I click on the next image, the previous image disappears. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#showImage').click(function() {
        $('#imageDialog').dialog({
          modal: true
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="imageDialog" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/126th-anniversary-of-the-public-opening-of-the-eiffel-tower-4812727050567680-hp.jpg">
  </div>
  <a id="showImage">Show images</a> 

</body>

</html>
```